# How to assign a values of variable to array in unix script

Tags: arrays, shell, unix

> Ex:

```
      $cat macro  
        File abc.txt  
        File xyz.csv  
        File bdc.txt  
        File lkm.csv  
        File cde.txt
```

> Doing grep to get only *.txt file names

```
 $grep -oh "\w*xml\w*" macro  
   abc.txt  
   bdc.txt  
   cde.txt
```

> Now i need to get those grep result to an array, the given code below is not working fine. I can able to store the grep result all in single variable not in separate variables i.e as array

```
  $cat txt.sh  
       var=$(grep -oh "\w*xml\w*" macro)  
        echo ${var[0]} #echo var ---both displays same result.
```

> Output

```
abc.txt bdc.txt cde.txt
```

> But i want them in array with values to be assigned as the following

```
  >var[0]=abc.txt  
  >var[1]=bdc.txt  
  >var[2]=cde.txt
```

Note: The number of xml files may vary. so it should dynamic. I m also working on it..
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately arrays are a nonstandard extension provided by some shells, you need to specify which one you're using (at least to know if the first element has index 1 or 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

Your var variable is not an array.Consider It as just a single variable in which results from grep are separated by spaces. This might be a workaround.

```
for eachval in var
do
echo $eachval
#process operations 
done
```

Each iteration of the loop gives an item from the variable.If you are sure that you want an array variable, initialize it in the loop

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your shell script just set the IFS shell variable to \n to seperate the fields by '\n'

```
IFS=$'\n'
$cat txt.sh  
var=$(grep -oh "\w*xml\w*" macro)  
echo ${var[0]} #echo var ---both displays same result.
```

**Explanantion:** : $IFS is bash's input field separator, setting it to the newline character only (\n) ensures that your output lines won't be split on whitespace so that you can save each line as a separate array element. Without this, each word of your command's output would be a different element.

Depending on what you want to do, it might be a good idea to save the old value of $IFS and restore it after the array is read:

```
oldifs="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(echo -e "foo bar\nbaz bar"))
IFS="$oldifs"
```